# CPU time (flops), matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

A particular computer takes about 0.2 seconds to multiply two 1500 x 1500 matrices. About how long would you guess the computer would take to multiply two 3000 x 3000 matrices.

Comment: It depends on the computer architecture.

Answer (score 2):

matrix-matrix product has a $O(n^3)$ complexity, hence  $2\times size\Rightarrow 8\times\text{CPU time}$. With your example, CPU time is $1.6$ sec.

Comment: This is actually not correct. The best algorithm for matrix multiplication is the Coppersmith–Winograd-Algorithmus with a runtime of $O(n^{2.3727})$. The Strassen-Algorithmus is$O(n^{2.807})$. There is currently no algorithm with $O(n^2)$ time complexity for any input of two matrices !!!!!

Comment: Thanks, I answered without paying attention, obviously the complexity of naive matrix-matrix product is $O(n^3)$ and not $O(n^2)$ as I wrote 
Inadvertently before.